# Button function in python with not working self.clicked

Tags: python, pygame

Been writing a button function however `self.clicked` does not keep its value after `MOUSEBUTTONUP`, is there a better method or a way to keep `self.clicked` value?

code:

```
def check_clicked(self,event):
    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.clicked = True
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.clicked == True:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: What framework are you using? Qt? what package does `pg` refer to?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title of the question. If one of the answers solved the problem, accept it by clicking on the checkmark below the arrows. Also, please read the [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off, although that should throw an error;

```
def check_clicked(self,event):
if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            self.clicked = True
elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #<<<<< Change indentation here
        if self.clicked == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Assuming your indentation is correct, I believe the issue is that you are not actually defining `self.clicked`, just checking it is true of not.

Try the following;

```
elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    self.clicked = True
    if self.clicked == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Although it's redundant to check if `self.clicked` is true before defining it. Just use;

```
def check_clicked(self,event):
if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            self.clicked = True
elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        self.clicked = True
        return True
```

Comment: @JuliaKunikowska you're welcome, please consider marking the question with a tick if it helped solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points - you may want to check collidepoint even for the UP event to make sure that the user has intended the click, or if he/she has changed their mind.  Second, you can use a 'self.down' variable to track that the button has been pressed, and set 'clicked' only upon seeing the UP event.

```
def check_clicked(self,event):
    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            self.clicked = False
            self.down = False
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.down = True
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.down and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.clicked = True
            else:
                self.clicked = False
            self.down = False

    return self.clicked
```